# KeystoneJS plural option not working in AdminUI

Tags: node.js, model, keystonejs

Even if i set the plural option in the list when defining the model,
in the Admin UI it does not show up, it keeps showing the default trailing 's'.

my model:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Pollo = new keystone.List('Pollo', {
    map:{ name: 'nome',},
    autokey:{path:'slug', from: 'nome', unique: true},
    plural: 'polli'
});
```

so in the Admin UI i see "pollos" instead of "polli"

Comment: In your `keystone.List(...` also add `label` and `singular` options in addition to `plural` and test if it works.

Comment: Yes now it works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `keystone.List('Pollo', { ... })` options, you need to also add `label` and `singular` options in addition to `plural`.